# Hot reload and hot restart not working in vivo z1 pro?

Tags: flutter

I have vivo z1 pro in which hot rreload and hot restart is not working while runing command flutter run it stuck on the observerity listner

Comment: tried to run it with `-v` flag?

Comment: Did you try to hot reload/restart while the program execution was paused by a breakpoint or uncaught error?

Comment: yes but it stuck on observetry